# Footnotes don't show properly (don't change line automatically)

Tags: footnotes

I'm writing my thesis, and this is my settings from my lab's template (I added and commented on some lines)

```tex
%\RequirePackage[hyphens]{url}
\documentclass[12pt,a4j,twoside]{report}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.2}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}
\setlength\floatsep{24pt}
\setlength\textfloatsep{24pt}
\setlength\intextsep{24pt}
\setlength\abovecaptionskip{1.5pt}
\graphicspath{{./imgs/}}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{bm}
%\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{textcomp}
% \usepackage{subfig}
% \usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[ipaex]{pxchfon}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{footmisc}

%\bibliographystyle{jplain}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\pagestyle{headings}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{9.6mm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-10.4mm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{160mm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.4mm}
\setlength{\headheight}{10mm}
\setlength{\headsep}{10mm}
\setlength{\footskip}{10mm}
\setlength{\textheight}{222mm}

\newcommand{\argmin}{\mathop{\rm arg~min}\limits}
\newcommand{\argminN}{\mathop{\rm arg~minN}\limits}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Figures}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Tables}

\usepackage{verbatim}
%\linespread{2}

\begin{document}
```

I'm using `\footnote{\url{https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/35/Structural_diagrams_of_unidirectional_and_bidirectional_recurrent_neural_networks.png}}`

However, this is the result

[image]

When I copied my settings to an new empty overleaf project, the footnote seems to be normal.

[image]

And the generated link is clickable, while it is unclickable in my original project.

This is so confusing to me as I can't think out a reason of this. And I think it is an urgent problem for me. Does anyone know the possible reasons?

The overleaf editor says `Overfull \hbox (285.14946pt too wide) in paragraph at lines X`, but I dont think this is the reason?

PS: 1. After commenting the line `\usepackage{hyperref}` with `%`, the footnote shows normally, but it is still unclickable. I don't really understand what has happened.

2. I checked and found that the original project is compiled with latex, and the thesis template seems to be only able to work under latex (from the requirement of my lab). The new project is compiled with pdflatex. When I changed pdflatex to latex for the new project, the same problem occured.

Comment: `\usepackage{xurl}` breaks URLs, try that instead of the `url` package

Comment: @JamesT It is still the same, the footnote exceeds the page, and it is still unclickable.

Comment: Can you make your code compile then so it can be troubleshooted please? I have code working on OverLeaf that I reduced down, can you include the problematic footnotes, example other footnotes and the minimum code required to reduce your issue please? Failing that, you can copy all your documents to a new project if needed. Have you deleted all your `aux`, `log` files? Click on `Logs and output files` next to `Recompile`, then click `clear cached files` the red button at the bottom and see if the error persists

Comment: @JamesT After commenting the line `\usepackage{hyperref}` with `%`, the footnote shows normally, but it is still unclickable. I don't really understand what has happened.

Comment: @user900476 If it works in a new project but not in your old, check the sidebar to see if both versions use the same texlive versions. Old projects aren't automatically updated.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thank you! I checked and found that the original project is compiled with latex, and the thesis template seems to be only able to work under latex (from the requirement of my lab). The new project is compiled with pdflatex. When I changed pdflatex to latex for the new project, the same problem occured.

Comment: That's the compiler, if you look underneath `compiler` there is `TeX live version`, check the year on both of them to see if they're the same. It will rule different versions out as the issue at least

Comment: @JamesT It seems I can only use plain Latex under my lab's template, so I tried `TeX live version` under `compiler` from 2014 to 2022, and it is still the same problem.

Comment: You say that you compile with `latex`, but isn't it `platex`? Because with `latex`, I obtain this error: ``pxchfon.sty:12: LaTeX Error: This file needs format `pLaTeX2e' but this is `LaTeX2e'``. Also, your preamble is strange, with 2 times `\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb}`, and another repetitions (about the **url** package). But this is probably not the reason of your problem. You say it's an urgent problem, if you haven't find a solution before your deadline, use `https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=File:RNN_BRNN.png` as shorter URL (it's a redirection to your original file).

Comment: If you compile a very minimal document (`\documentclass{article}`& `\usepackage{hyperref}` in the preamble) and your long `\footnote{\url{...}}` in the body, with **latex**, the url in footnote is broken before the margin. But if you compile with **platex**, the url runs in the margin. The package `plautopatch` (`\RequirePackage{plautopatch}` before `\documentclass`) says it patchs `hyperref` for compatibility with **platex**. But halas it is insuffisant, in my very minimal test file, the url runs in the margin after adding `\RequirePackage{plautopatch}`. `\url{}` don't work with **platex**?

Comment: @quark67 Thank you. It is compiled with Latex, not pdfLatex. I compiled it on Overleaf.

Comment: If you use `LaTeX`, then may I know, how you created PDF?

Comment: @user900476 Don't confuse **platex** with **pdflatex** nor with **latex**. Overleaf don't provide the option to compile with **platex** but the package pxchfon needs it. Halas, I don't know how to make hyperref compatible with **platex**, as plautopatch seems not suffisant.